# Notify parent instance about property change

Tags: python, class, oop, properties, setter

I have these two classes:

```
class Status(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._message = ''

    @property
    def message(self):
        return self._message

    @message.setter
    def message(self, value):
        self._message = value


class Buddy(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.status = Status()

    def status_updated(self):
        # this should be called when self.status.message is changed
```

and I use them like this:

```
buddy = Buddy('John')
buddy.status.message = 'Hello world!'  # this should call Buddy.status_updated
```

I want `Buddy.status_updated` to be called when I modify the `message` property of `Status`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to store a reference *back* to the parent; python values do not track where they are stored (there can be multiple places that refer to your `Status()` instances):

```
class Status(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self._message = ''
        self._parent = parent

    @property
    def message(self):
        return self._message

    @message.setter
    def message(self, value):
        self._message = value
        if self._parent is not None:
            self._parent.status_updated()


class Buddy(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.status = Status(self)

    def status_updated(self):
        # this should be called when self.status.message is changed
```

Comment: I was afraid that this will be the answer. Thank you!

Comment: The alternative is to use some kind of event system (subscribers, event publishers, etc).

Answer (score 1):

In each case you need somehow to register you want to "listen" to other's object property changes. I would suggest simple solution like this:

```
class Status(object):
    def __init__(self, on_message_change=None):
        self._message, self._on_message_change = '', on_message_change

    @property
    def message(self):
        return self._message

    @message.setter
    def message(self, value):
        if self._on_message_change:
            self._on_message_change(self._message, value)
        self._message = value


class Buddy(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.status = Status(self.status_updated)

    def status_updated(self, old_value, new_value):
        print("status changed '%s' -> '%s'" % (old_value, new_value))

b = Buddy("someone")
b.status.message = "init"
b.status.message = "new"
```

output is:

```
status changed '' -> 'init'
status changed 'init' -> 'new'
```